# Highliting a row in jQuery with specific content in a td

Tags: jquery, html-table, tablerow

So far I can get my code to highlite the specific td, but even better would be to highlite the entire row. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
var mySearch = 'No';
$('table tbody tr td:contains("' + mySearch + '")').filter
(function(){
if($.trim($(this).text()) == mySearch)
    $(this).addClass("prequal-status-n");       
});
```

Comment: You might as well lose the `:contains` bit of the selector. It will slow your code down significantly, since it is a jQuery extension, so disables the browser's native (querySelectorAll) functionality. Since you're doing the `== mySearch` test later on, you don't need the `:contains` call at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing `$(this).addClass("prequal-status-n")` to `$(this).closest('tr').addClass("prequal-status-n")` you can select the entire row rather than just a cell within the row.

Here is a jsfiddle of using `.closest()` to select the `tr` parent tag of a cell: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/LhbUG/

Note: `.closest('tr')` can be replaced by `.parent()` as the direct parent of the `td` tag is a `tr` tag. Just keep in mind that using `.parent()` restricts your `$(this)` selector to being a direct descendant of the `tr` tag.

Here's some documentation for ya:

- `.parent()`: http://api.jquery.com/parent
- `.closest()`: http://api.jquery.com/closest

Comment: In this case i'd use parent(), i see no need for closest()

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("td:contains('" + mySearch + "')").closest("tr").toggleClass("prequal-status-n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use closparentest() and find the tr

```
var mySearch = 'No';
$('table tbody tr td:contains("' + mySearch + '")').filter
(function(){
if($.trim($(this).text()) == mySearch)
    $(this).parent().addClass("prequal-status-n");       
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var mySearch = 'No';
$('table tbody tr td:contains("' + mySearch + '")')
                   .parent("tr").addClass("prequal-status-n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to select the `<tr>` that  contains the `<td>`:

```
$(this).closest("tr").addClass(...);
```

From the API documentation for `closest`:

> Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.